# Compare project in Intellij to the one checked into subversion?

Tags: java, svn, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I'm an Intellij noob using v13.  I have imported a subversion project.  To see the changes between a file I'm working on and the file checked into subversion I can right click on a file, Subversion->Compare with Latest Repository Version.  Works great.  However, now I want to see ALL of the differences in my project.

When I right-click on the project, Subversion -> Compare with Branch -> truck (trunk) only one of the two changed files is shown.  I can right click on the file not shown in that list and (using the method above) confirm that Intellij sees the file has been changed.

How does one compare a current project to the one checked into subversion?  My vision is to get a list of all files added, changed, etc. and then be able to click on any of them to see the change.

Comment: When you say you "right-click on the project" -> where exactly are you clicking? It's important to click on the project root, which is parent to both the changes you want to see. Can you also left click on the project root, so the tree root is selected, and then try the same operation via `VCS` menu -> `Svn` -> `Compare with branch`, what happens then?

Comment: I am right clicking on the project name that appears just under "Project" on the project panel.  Right-clicking on it then clicking Subversion brings up the same menu as the method you specify.  Interestingly, this seems to be only showing the changes that were checked in after I updated my local version.  It is NOT catching all of the changes that I make locally (I can only seem them hunting around for them as described below).  I also should have mentioned the "Compare with Latest Repository Version" is greyed out when the project is highlights.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Changes` Tool Window (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>).

It will show you all your changes in the current project and you can also diff the files easily.

[image]

So now you can track all changes in the project in the `Changes` Tool Window. Here there are currently no changes.

[image]

So now I want to update the author of this `Bar` class from `matbac` to my Stackoverflow alias `maba`. As you can see in the following image the changes are being shown both in the editor view and in the `Changes` window.

[image]

If you now want to see the difference in the changed files (changes from what is currently checked in in subversion) you can right-click on a file (or mark several files or even mark the root part) in the `Changes` window and select `Show Diff` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

[image]

In the Diff window you can jump to next change using the Up/Down arrows (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>F7</kbd>). You can also go to Next/Prev file using the icons to the right (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>).

[image]

---

#### EDIT

So what if you use the `Incoming` part of the `Changes` window like so:

[image]

You can compare all local changes to the latest revisions in your SVN Repo.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I can use this method to see all of my changes (combining the information on the local and incoming tabs).  However, I think there should be a single tab where I can see a full diff between local and svn repo version (similar to the Compare with Branch - trunk" but with ALL differences).  As far as I can tell, that full diff is not available for a project in ONE view.  Correct?